# rails partial render gives undefined methods for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm rendering a partial from an offer's view:

```
<%= render partial: 'parent_offers_table', locals: { :parent_offers => [offer.parent_offer] } %>
```

And then, in _parent_offers_table:

```
<%= render partial: 'parent_offer', collection: parent_offers %>
```

However, in _parent_offer I cannot do anything with the parent_offer variable.  I get
undefined methods for nil:NilClass:

```
<tr>
    <td><%= parent_offer.created_at %></td>
    <td><%= parent_offer.version %></td>
    <td><%= parent_offer.client.try(:name) %></td>
    <td>
    ............
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

instead:

```
<%= render partial: 'parent_offer', collection: parent_offers %>
```

try:

```
<%= render partial: 'parent_offer', locals: {parent_offers: parent_offers} %>
```

or:

```
<%= render 'parent_offer', parent_offers: parent_offers %>
```

Comment: Also, you should make sure the variable name used in partial complies with `model_name` of the collection you'd like to render.

Comment: @IS04 with these two solutions I now get undefined local variable or method `parent_offer'

Comment: (fixed) if you need `parent_offers` just change `collection` to it

Answer (score 1):

**Collection**

```
<%= render partial: "parent_offer", collection: parent_offers, as: :parent_offer %>
```

Although the `collection` partial rendering functionality is truly amazing, we found it has one major drawback, in that it's very difficult to manage the `object` you call in the partial itself.

If you're calling your own object name, you'll be best to [use the `as:` argument](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#local-variables) to define the local variable:

> To use a custom local variable name within the partial, specify the
>   :as option in the call to the partial:
>
> `<%= render partial: "product", collection: @products, as: :item %>`
>
> With this change, you can access an instance of the @products
>   collection as the item local variable within the partial.